# Can't install aiohttp==2.0.6 on Alpine Linux v3.5

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pip, aiohttp, alpine-linux

I'm using a fresh install of Alpine Linux v3.5 with edge/main repos

These are the commands I'm running:

```
$ echo "http://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/alpine/edge/main" > /etc/apk/repositories
$ apk update
$ apk add python3
$ pip3 install aiohttp==2.0.6
```

And that's the error that I'm getting from the last command:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aiohttp==2.0.6
(from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.5.0,
0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4, 0.6.5, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3,
0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.8.4, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.10.0,
0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.2,
0.14.3, 0.14.4, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.15.3, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2,
0.16.3, 0.16.4, 0.16.5, 0.16.6, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.17.2, 0.17.3, 0.17.4,
0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.18.2, 0.18.3, 0.18.4, 0.19.0, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2,
0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.21.2, 0.21.4, 0.21.5, 0.21.6, 0.22.0a0, 0.22.0b0,
0.22.0b1, 0.22.0b2, 0.22.0b3, 0.22.0b4, 0.22.0b5, 0.22.0b6, 0.22.0,
0.22.1, 0.22.2, 0.22.3, 0.22.4, 0.22.5, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.5,
1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.1,
1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4,
2.0.5, 2.0.6.post1)
```

On the ArchLinux host, however, everything installs correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having the same problem.
I removed in my requirements.txt the version name and it worked. I checked the version than installed:

```
Collecting aiohttp
  Downloading aiohttp-2.0.6-1.tar.gz (1.1MB)
Collecting amqp==1.4.9
  Downloading amqp-1.4.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51kB)
Collecting anyjson==0.3.3
  Downloading anyjson-0.3.3.tar.gz
```